# Printing Order Summary in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Does store generate a printable order summary for customers?  Anyone do this with any success. Customer wants a "print invoice" button on the order summary page, and I'm not sure how to go about that.  I tried using the HTML/CSS email that goes to the customer (that would print nicely), but of course, when I put that in a template called "invoice" and link to it from the Order Confirmation page, it doesn't parse any of the customer/order variables.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [**Orders Tag**](https://exp-resso.com/docs/orders_tag.html):

The order_hash should be present in the "success" page URL as a segment and you can grab that and pass it to another template with a link like this:

```
<a href="/checkout/print/{segment_3}">Print Invoice</a>
```

Then in your "Print" template use the following to get your invoice data:

```
{exp:store:orders order_hash="{segment_3}"}
    {if no_orders}
        {redirect='404'}
    {/if}
    <!-- display order details here -->
{/exp:store:orders}
```