# Where to view order hash?

Tags: expresso-store

I'm new to Exp-resso store. According to the docs; I can view an order through its order hash as per below:

```
{exp:store:orders order_hash="xxxx"}
```

How do I retrieve the order hash?

Edit: Referring to this answer: [Printing Order Summary in Expresso Store](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24045/printing-order-summary-in-expresso-store)

It seems that order hash only available via success page? Is there a way I can retrieve it for later viewing; ala url_title or entry_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to get access to the `{order_hash}` tag, the most common way that you would probably see it is a  result of placing a successful order. This would be achieved by adding `return="order/ORDER_HASH"` to the final checkout tag.

The next way you can access the order_hash is in your receipt templates that will get sent out to customers on a completed order. You will want to use the `{exp:store:orders}` tag pair in your receipt templates to get all of the relative order details and this would allow you to create a link to the particular hash (this assumes you have a template group called orders and the template is looking for the hash in the segment_2. You may need to adjust to your site.)

```
{exp:store:orders}
 Order ID: {order_id}
 View Invoice: {path="orders/{order_hash}"}
{/exp:store:orders}
```

The other way you can access the order_hash was touched on by Rodrigo in his answer but you should be able to use the `{order_hash}` tag even though it is not listed on the orders documentation page.

```
{exp:store:orders member_id="CURRENT_USER"}"}
 Order ID: {order_id}<br />
 <a href='{path="orders/{order_hash}"}'>View Invoice</a>
{/exp:store:orders}
```

The nice thing about using the order_hash over the order_id as has been mentioned is that it prevents a malicious user from being able to quickly guess other order numbers which might include sensitive information such as address or phone number.

If you do decide to use order_id instead you should make sure that your template to show single orders also includes a conditional for the current member to prevent users from seeing other users orders.

```
{exp:store:orders member_id="CURRENT_USER"}" order_id="{segment_2}"}
 Order ID: {order_id}<br />
{/exp:store:orders}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I wonder why it is not mentioned in the docs. And if possible; allow admin to view the hash string inside the order detail page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a listing of orders by the logged user using:

```
{exp:store:orders member_id="CURRENT_USER"}
  <a href="{path='/order/{order_id}'}"> view order </a>
{/exp:store:orders}
```

Then on that template:

{exp:store:orders order_id="{segment_2}"}